# Express routing - asynchronous longpolled requests take a long time to hit

Tags: node.js, express, routes, long-polling

Assume a simple routing like this one:

```
var express = require( 'express' );
var app = express();

app.get( '/', function( req, res ) {
    console.log( "Route hit" );
} );

app.listen( 8081 );
```

Requesting the route on a browser via multiple tabs (localhost:8081) results in an unexpectedly long pause between the request and the actual registration of the request:

```
C:\tasks\node_programs\test>node main.js
1: route hit -> 6917
2: route hit -> 27697
3: route hit -> 28146
4: route hit -> 28599
```

The time difference between me refreshing the tab for the request **route hit 1** and **route hit 2,3 and 4** is at most 1 second.

Why and how do I make it register all events immediately after it is sent?

*Sidenote: Ofcourse, if I send a response in the route, everything works fine, but I want to register the request and send a response only once some criteria are met (in the actual application I wait for an event to be triggered).*

**SOLVED: Do not test HTTP request issues via browser**

Instead u can use e.g. this script:

```
var requestify = require('requestify');

var i = 0;
while ( i < 10 ) {
  i++;
  requestify.get('http://localhost:8081')
    .then(function(response) {
        // Get the response body (JSON parsed or jQuery object for XMLs)
        response.getBody();
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: It may be that the browser is waiting a specific amount of time for the first request to get answered before sending new requests (browser will also limit the # of connections to the same host, who knows what else they'll do). In other words: don't use browsers for testing HTTP issues.

Comment: Correct. When I send 10 requests using a simple node script it works without a problem.. should have thought this was the issue